# True or False: A Borel set is a countable union of disjoint intervals and a measure zero set

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Basically the title.

To give more context, suppose I have a Borel set $B$ with $B\subset [0,1]$. As an example, consider a situation where I am interested in computing some expectation over $B$ with respect to the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. If my conjecture is true, then I can write:

$$
\int_B \dfrac{g(x)dx}{\mu(B)} = \sum_{i=0}^n \int_{a_i}^{b_i} \dfrac{g(x)dx}{b_i-a_i}
$$

for some $(a_i, b_i)_{i\in N}$. This is indeed what I need. However, I couldn't find any reference to such a result or a counter-example to my conjecture.

In fact, if it is not the case that any Borel set can be written in this manner, what is the largest class of measurable sets for which this is true?

Comment: Not true, take a fat Cantor set. It has positive measure and is totally disconnected (i.e. the only intervals it contains are singeltons).

Comment: ... and a fat Cantor set shows even more: the counterexample could be a closed set.

Answer (score 4):

The set of all irrational numbers is a counter-example. Any interval contained in it is  a sigletion since this set has no interior. If your conlusion holds then the set of all irrational numbers itself would have measure $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Really nice! Much simpler than my fat Cantor set.

Comment: Of course!

In that case, my problem with the expectation is still easily solvable. I will convince myself that this is why I didn't think about it before posting here.